# Electron-builder macOS notarization problem with puppeteer library: Not all binaries are signed

Tags: macos, puppeteer, code-signing, electron-builder, notarize

I am currently struggling with notarizing my app with electron builder for macOS! The app uses puppeteer which causes the error that the ".localChromium" folder does not get signed! I already tried a lot of things but I was not able to fix this problem.

Here is my configuration for the package.json file:

```
"build": {
"asar": true,
"asarUnpack": "node_modules/puppeteer/.local-chromium/**/*",
"publish": [
  {
    "provider": "generic",
    "url": "http://www.someProvider.com"
  }
],
"appId": "SomeApp",
"afterSign": "notarize.js",
"mac": {
  "icon": "build/logo.png",
  "category": "public.app-category.productivity",
  "target": [
    "dmg", "zip"
  ],
  "signIgnore": "/node_modules/puppeteer/.local-chromium/",
  "gatekeeperAssess": false
}
```

This is just the lastest configuration I tried! (I read about the signIgnore property on a GitHub post where someone mentioned a similar problem and was able to fix it with this, but this hasn't changed anything - I tried multiple paths in case this one is a wrong expression). I also tried to set the "hardendedRuntime" property to true.

To use puppeteer-core is not an option!

These are some errors I receive - they all state that the content in the .localChromium folder isn't signed:

[image]

Does anyone know how to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by using [puppeteer-in-electron](https://www.npmjs.com/package/puppeteer-in-electron). Just replace `import puppeteer from 'puppeteer'` with `import puppeteer from 'puppeteer-core'`. That way `.local-chromium` wont be included with your electron app because it will just use the chromium that is built in along with electron. You will also need to remove `puppeteer` from `package.json`